# How would u relate arc length to chord length?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, arc-length

What is relationship of arc length of 2 points of a circle and if you connect a chord to the same points of arc.

In the book it says. Points A and B of an arc is 2x length
So the chord length is 2 sin(x)

How come?
What is relationship of arc with sin()

Comment: Read Wikipedia article  [Ptolemy's table of chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $l$ be the length of  the arc and let $\alpha$ the angle on this arc. We have that:
$$\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}=\frac{l}{2\pi r}\leftrightarrow\alpha=\frac{l}{r}$$
where $r$ is the radius of the circle. Also, we know that:
$$L=2r\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$$
by the trigonometric properties of $\sin(x)$. Substituting, we have:
$$L=2r\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=2r\sin\left(\frac{l}{2r}\right)$$
where $L$ is the length of the chord.

Note that the answer of your book is not correct because if you consider $-2\leq2\sin(\alpha)\leq2$ and so it can't represent the length of all chords of a circle with diameter $10$.

Comment: $L=\color{red}2r\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$.

Comment: @user: yes, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Plz excuse me. It is 2x arc length equals 2 sine (x). Actually i dont get it.

Comment: @Asim: it's $L=2r\sin\left(\frac{l}{2r}\right)$ the lenght of the chord, while the lenght of the arc is $l$.

Comment: Thank u so much now i get ur point. So  we have to involve 2 in any case.  Because i thought if 2x arc = 2 sine x than it would be same as arc x = sine x. But we have to divide x by 2 than take sine of it and THAN multiply with 2. Right?

Comment: @Asim: yes, we have to involve $2$ in any case because of trigonometric proprieties of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Asim:  if this answer has been useful maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: I already voted up. How do u favorite it?

Comment: @Asim: click on the tick under bar of votes.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think what the book says is correct, for example if the arc length was pi, on a unit circle, then the chord length would apparently be Sin(pi) which is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The arc length is $\dfrac{d\alpha}2$ and the corresponding chord $d\sin\dfrac\alpha2$. Hence

$$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{d\alpha}2,\\\sin x=d\sin\dfrac\alpha2.\end{cases}$$

This is true when $x$ is the half of the aperture angle and the diameter is unit.

Comment: Sorry i edited the questio . It is actually arc = 2x = (2 sin x)